# Can't install Intel MKL

Tags: intel-mkl, intel-oneapi

I've downloaded two different versions of the Intel OneAPI BaseKit Offline Installer:

```
w_BaseKit_p_2021.2.0.2871_offline.exe
```

and

```
w_BaseKit_p_2022.1.2.154_offline.exe
```

Both properly extract, start the `bootstrapper.exe`, show a loading screen, and then crash and disappear.

I have unchecked "Remove temporarily extracted files after installation" to inspect what gets extracted, and double clicked `bootstrapper.exe` in the extracted folders. Both have the same problem: a system requirements check with some download messages pictured below

[image: System Checker]

Followed by the loading screen that disappears with nothing left:

[image: ![Loading Screen]

Finally, there is a path created with a ton of files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\Installer
```

Within that directory there is an `installer.exe`. If I run it, the following screen comes up:

[image: installer.exe]

Which resembles the actual installer I expect from `bootstrapper.exe` but there's nothing to be done with it. When I exit from this screen, it asks are you sure, to which I answer yes, and then the whole path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\` gets deleted.

I have no idea how to debug this, and I'm not even sure this is the appropriate place to ask. I considered superuser, but there are similar questions here.

Does anyone have any tips for researching this problem? I've installed successfully on other machines before. This is a new laptop with Windows 10. I can still successfully run the `bootstrapper.exe` on the old laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the `bootstrapper.exe` to work by running in compatibility mode (Right Click -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Run compatibility troubleshooter).

After running this the installer has a compatibility warning, but I just clicked next:

[Installer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyXMC.png)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to a known issue discussed on the Intel forum here:

https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Registration/KNOWN-ISSUE-with-Intel-oneAPI-Toolkits-versions-2022-1-and-2022/m-p/1361803

It seems that currently, installation of Intel oneAPI Toolkits (versions 2022.1 and 2022.1.2) won't work if Visual Studio 2022 17.1.x is installed. Based on the discussion, the options appear to be either:

- Downgrade to Visual Studio 2022 17.0.6
- Wait until an update to either Intel oneAPI and/or Visual Studio is released

Comment: jhader's solution worked for me but thank you for the explanation (I have 17.1.0 installed, so this is definitely the case for me).

Comment: Are you able to integrate basekit with VS by running the installer in compatibility???

Comment: I believe Intel has now fixed this issue if you install the latest versions of Visual Studio and oneAPI.